# How to send data from server to client in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to send data to port, and use it with spark streaming. Spark and port connected. i can send the data, but spark cannot print it.

```
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 8000))
serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    print "connected"
    data = "osman tamer"
    connection.send(data)
```

spark

```
import findspark
findspark.init('C:\spark')
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
sc = SparkContext("local[2]","test")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",8000)
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1))
word_count = words.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
word_count.pprint()
ssc.start()
```

Comment: Can you explain to us what is happening? Is it showing an error? Or what is it doing?

Comment: nothing happening. console prints "connected" but spark cannot print anything. it has to print the data i send

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667771/python-send-csv-data-to-spark-streaming
this link helped me a lot.